# Are laravel query results encoded?

Tags: php, laravel-4

In my laravel app, I am trying to trim a result that I get from database. The trim() is not removing the last space in the string.

The code is this

```
$institutes = Institute::all();

foreach ($institutes as $institute) {
    $str = $institute->name;
    $str = trim($str);  //doesn't remove the trailing space
    $len = strlen($str);
}
```

Now, first of all, the length of `$str` is 1 more than what it should be. It should be `20` but it somehow shows `21`. Another thing, the last character is a `space` according to my input.

When I try to print the last(21st) and second last(20th) characters - the last character(which should not even be there) and and the second last character which should be a `space` turns out to be something like [this](http://d.pr/i/y0Ll).

A `dot` on browser(as the second last character) appears for almost a second and then it disappears. Now, what is going on? Why is this happening?

Please give me directions or else I am going to go out of my mind!

**Update:**

This is dump of the variable `$str`-

```
string(21) "Vidyalankar Classes "
```

Comment: I just tried to do the same in my laravel 4.1 application.
And There's no extra space in my strings.

Comment: Please show actual code, not "something like"...  Your example has no trimming in it so it's hard to see where something could be going wrong.

Comment: @PhillSparks done. It doesn't have much to do with trimming. I mentioned it just to create base. Problem is surely something else.

Comment: how about [rtrim](http://php.net/rtrim) to remove **trailing** spaces.

Comment: @majimboo tried that too, didn't work

Comment: @user1708762 would be better if you gave a dump of the `str`.

Comment: @user1708762 added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a feeling that the trailing space you are referring to is a non-utf8 character.

Try removing all invalid characters instead, rather than trimming.

```
foreach ($institutes as $institute) {
  $str = $institute->name;
  // be careful, try to double check, might also remove valid utf 8 characters like Chinese characters.
  $str = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $str);
  $len = strlen($str);
}
```

---

refer to [trim](http://www.php.net/trim) documentation.

> This function returns a string with whitespace stripped from the beginning and end of str. Without the second parameter, trim() will strip these characters:

```
" " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary space.
"\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab.
"\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed).
"\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), a carriage return.
"\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.
"\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab.
```

---

You can also try another approach, like

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\. -]/','', $str);

// using trim, trims off invalid characters
$str = trim($str, "\x20..\x7F");
```